# Count of Special Characters by each column in awk

Tags: unix, awk, scripting

I have a comma delimited file below with 3 columns

```
101,daf*s,HJ
102*,dft,GH*
103,hh*f,FF
10*J,ff*H,P
```

I want to count number of `*` by each column and want output something like below using awk

```
Column 1:2
Column 2:3
Column 3:1
```

and if possible I want to make this code as dynamic as possible , in sense if the number of columns also change, code should be able to print count of * by each column.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]+=gsub(/[*]/, "", $i)
}
END {
    for (i=1; i in a; i++) print "Column "i":"a[i]+0
}' file
Column 1:2
Column 2:3
Column 3:1
```

Set the Field separator to `,`. Iterate through the columns and using `gsub` function capture the return value per column and keep adding to the array.

In the `END` block, iterate over the number of columns and print the output.